# Deploying and hosting Laravel Rest api along with a Angular App and mysql DB

Tags: angular, laravel, deployment, hosting, devops

I implemented a backend rest Api using PHP Laravel 8, an Angular 10 App that uses the Laravel Apis, and the backend is connected to Mysql DB.

The project is already done and I would like to host it for production use. So any help on which cloud services/platform should I use, and what steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using deployer for some time now. It's really a great app that helps you automate the deployment procedure directly from the terminal.

https://deployer.org

My command looks like this:

```
 dep deploy prod
```

It takes care of everything for you.

To install, type this in your local environment

> curl -LO https://deployer.org/deployer.phar mv deployer.phar
> /usr/local/bin/dep chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dep

Then type

```
 dep init
```

Choose Laravel

That will add a deploy.php script to the root of your project. You just need to config everything up. Documentation is available on the website

https://deployer.org/docs/getting-started.html

As for hosting, You have a lot of different options at different prices. Depends on the nature of your project and the traffic it will generate. In most cases, a godaddy account is all you need. But for something more robust, amazon or google offers very good cloud-based hosting. But the price is very expensive.

This is an opinion based question and should not be on stackoverflow. Expect the question to be removed.